# css Get element to move to right within other element

Tags: css, rights

I am working on a calendar app and having trouble getting the date to move where I want it within the day.  Specifically, with the square for the date, I cannot get the day number to move to the top right.  have tried float:right and align-text: right without success.  Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AzsrJ/3/) and the code:

css

```
table.calendar {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 520px;
}
span.day-number  {
    vertical-align:top; 
//    text-aligh:right;
    background:#999; 
    z-index:2; 
    top:0px; 
    align-right:+70px; 
    padding:4px; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    width:18px; 
    text-align:center;
}
td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np {
 //   float:left;
    vertical-align:top; 
    width:70px; 
    padding:5px 25px 5px 5px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #999; 
    border-right:1px solid #999; 
}
div.event {
    display:inline;
    position:relative; 
    z-index:3; 
    top:15px;
    text-width: 70px;
}
```

html

```
 <table class="calendar">
    <tr>
        <td>Mon</td>
        <td>Tue</td>
        <td>Wed</td>
        <td>Thur</td>
        <td>Fri</td>
</tr>
<tr>
         <td class="calendar-day"><span class="day-number">14</span><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><span class="day-number">15</span><div>&nbsp;</div>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="calendar-day"><span class="day-number">16</span><div class="event">4:00PM<br>Go to gym</div></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"></td>
    <td class="calendar-day"><span class="day-number">18</span><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></td>
            </tr></table>
```

CSS is not my strong suite so I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: `float:right` on `.day-number` works for me.  Which element did you try it on?

Comment: That moves it a bit to the right at about the 60% mark on my browser (Firefox) but I would like it to be flush to the line to the right so it is in upper right hand corner.  Does it move it all the way to the right on your browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

http://jsfiddle.net/sanpopo/byRTn/

```
table.calendar {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 520px;
}
span.day-number  {
    vertical-align:top; 
    background:#999; 
    z-index:2; 
    top:0px;    
    padding:4px; 
    color:#fff; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    width:18px; 
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
}
td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np {
 //   float:left;
    vertical-align:top; 
    width:70px; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #999; 
    border-right:1px solid #999; 

}
div.event {
    display:inline;
    position:relative; 
    z-index:3; 
    top:30px;
    text-width: 70px;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following in your CSS.

```
span.day-number  {
display:block;
float:right;
...
}

div.event {
display:inline; /* remove this line */ 
clear:right;
...
}
```

Update padding:

```
td.calendar-day, td.calendar-day-np {
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; 
...
```

}